# DataView and prototypical Inheritance

Tags: javascript, prototype

From what I've gleamed online, one way to extend an object in JavaScript is by first cloning it's prototype, then setting that prototype as the prototype of the subclass.

It doesn't appear to be working here though:

```
// Create constructor ...
function Packet(opcode, size) {
  DataView.call(this, new ArrayBuffer(size));
  setInt8(0, opcode);
}

// Extend DataView ...
Packet.prototype = Object.create(DataView.prototype);

// Create class method ...
Packet.prototype.send = function(websocket) {
  // Send packet here ...
  websocket.send(this.buffer);
  console.log('Packet sent!');
}

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1337");

ws.onopen = function() {
  var packet = new Packet(0, 5);

  // Create packet here ...
  packet.setInt32(1337);

  // Send packet over ws ...
  packet.send(ws);
}
```

Here I am attempting to extend DataView in order to create a binary "Packet" class backed internally by an ArrayBuffer.

Unfortunately when I try to create an instance of this class, JavaScript throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Constructor DataView requires 'new'(…)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all constructors allow you to call them, e.g. ES6 classes:

```
class Foo {}
new Foo(); // OK
Foo(); // error
Foo.call(); // error
```

However, [`DataView`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-dataview-constructor) can be subclassed using the `extends` syntax:

> The `DataView` constructor is designed to be subclassable. It may be
>   used as the value of an `extends` clause of a class definition.
>   Subclass constructors that intend to inherit the specified `DataView`
>   behaviour must include a `super` call to the `DataView` constructor to
>   create and initialize subclass instances with the internal state
>   necessary to support the [`DataView.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-dataview.prototype) built-in methods.

```
class Packet extends DataView {
  constructor(opcode, size) {
    super(new ArrayBuffer(size));
    this.setInt8(0, opcode);
  }
  send (websocket) {
    // Send packet here ...
  }
}
var packet = new Packet(0, 5);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!

I saw that this syntax was introduced in ES6. I was hesitant to use it because I wasn't sure how widely supported it was.

Do you know how compatible this syntax is with modern browsers?

Comment: See [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility). Note that `DataView` is also introduced by ES6 (but it has more compatibility because at first it was specified outside ECMAScript).

Comment: Is it possible to subclass DataView using only ES5 inheritance?

Comment: @curiousdannii No, DataView objects have an internal [[DataView]] slot, and you can't set it using ES5 ways.