# Extending DataView in TypeScript throws "Constructor DataView requires 'new'"

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I want to extend `DataView` with state and functionality as follows:

```js
export class MyDataView extends DataView
{
    public position: number;

    public constructor(buffer: ArrayBuffer | SharedArrayBuffer)
    {
        super(buffer);
    }

    public readInt32(): number
    {
        const result = this.getInt32(this.position);
        this.position += 4;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I then try to create an instance as follows:

```js
const fileSelector = document.getElementById("file-selector");
fileSelector.addEventListener("change", async (ev) =>
{
    const fileList = (<HTMLInputElement>ev.target).files;
    const arrayBuffer = await fileList[0].arrayBuffer();
    const myDataView = new MyDataView(arrayBuffer);
});
```

However, I get the following error logged in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Constructor DataView requires 'new'
    at MyDataView.DataView
    at new MyDataView (s. below)
```

Going to the location marked by it shows the following JS code. I'm not sure if it is correct. In a [similar JS-only issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068518/dataview-and-prototypical-inheritance%20similar%20JS-only%20issue), I saw that `super()` should be called here instead of `_super.call()`.

```js
function MyDataView(buffer) {
    var _this = this;
    _this = _super.call(this, buffer) || this;
    return _this;
}
```

How can I properly extend `DataView` in TypeScript? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "target" in your tsconfig.json is probably set to "es5" and there is no ES5 way of extending ES6 classes, like Map, Set, or DataView.

(source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10853#issuecomment-246211140)

The solution that worked for me is that I've set "target" to "es6" and then the transpiled code went from:

```js
var MyClass = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    __extends(BinaryIO, _super);
    function BinaryIO(buffer, byteOffset, byteLength) {
        var _this = _super.call(this, buffer, byteOffset, byteLength) || this;
        _this.position = 0;
        return _this;
    }
    ...
}
```

to

```js
class MyClass extends DataView {
    constructor(buffer, byteOffset, byteLength) {
        super(buffer, byteOffset, byteLength);
        this.position = 0;
    }
    ...
}
```